# How do I format time in MicroPython?

Tags: time, format, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

Using a Raspberry Pi Pico and MicroPython I am trying to convert `time.localtime()` to a string. I tried `.join()` but the Raspberry Pi Pico runs MicroPython:

```
from machine import Pin, I2C
from ssd1306 import SSD1306_I2C

now = time.localtime()
print("Current date and time: ")
print(now)

w = 128
h = 32

i2c = I2C(0, scl=Pin(17), sda=Pin(16), freq=200000)
addr = i2c.scan()[0]
oled = SSD1306_I2C(w, h, i2c, addr)

oled.fill(0)
oled.text("Raspberry Pi ", 5, 5)
olex.text("Hi Leo", 5, 15)

oled.show()
```

Comment: Could you share sample of expected date format you would like to have?

Comment: Date: Month/Day/Year such as (09/28/22) and Time: Hour:Minute such as (8:22)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import time

now = time.localtime()
print("Date: {}/{}/{}".format(now[1], now[2], now[0]))
print("Time: {}:{}".format(now[3], now[4]))
```

Your variable `now` has all required data- it consis of tuple

> (year, month, mday, hour, minute, second, weekday, yearday)

Documentation available [here](https://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/time.html#time.localtime)

Comment: Thank you so much! I saw the documentation I just couldn't figure out how to call the specific part of the tuple.